# Access Network router and find IP address (unknown gateway and gateway not shown)

Tags: networking

I have an old netgear router and I don't remember the gateway for it, whenever I connect to it over ethernet no gateway is specified. Is there any way to find the ip so that I can connect to it?

(I don't know what router type it is, its serial is 1JX167B007721)

## Update

So it was just the ethernet port on my laptop that was messed up. When I plugged the router to my old desktop it worked and gave me the default gateway (192.168.0.1)

The proper way to do this would be to iterate through all possible (common) ip addresses and ping them. The easiest way to do this would be to use batch and just run through the `ping` command.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time it'll be 192.168.1.1 . To start fresh make sure you do a complete reset on it. Hopefully there is a reset button on it, holding that for a few seconds should perform the clean reset.